# How to suppress 'value computed but not used' in C?

Tags: c, stm32, semaphore

Regarding the message 'value computed is not used', I find all sorts of explanations how to fix the corresponding code but I can't find any hint how to suppress this warning.

I have this perfectly fine code

```
HSEM->RLR[2] == (HSEM_CM4_CORE_ID | HSEM_PROC_ID | (1UL << 31));
```

This is the correct way to lock a semaphore in the STM32H745 as the semaphore is locked via a read. Since I know this is valid code, how do I suppress the warning for this particular line of code?

I am using gcc in the CubeIDE environment.

**Edited to add:**

Here's the code that I used to verify that the lock works:

```
#define HSEM_CM4_CORE_ID (1 << 8)  // CPU2 is CM4
#define HSEM_PROC_ID (0 << 0)
volatile uint32_t x;
x = HSEM->R[23] & (1 << 31);                                     // Read semaphore 23.
HSEM->RLR[23] == (HSEM_CM4_CORE_ID | HSEM_PROC_ID | (1 << 31));  // Lock semaphore 23.
x = HSEM->R[23] & (1 << 31);                                     // Read semaphore 23.
HSEM->R[23] = HSEM_CM4_CORE_ID | HSEM_PROC_ID;                   // Release semaphore 23.
x = HSEM->R[23] & (1 << 31);                                     // Read semaphore 23.
```

When I step through this code line by line with the debugger, the first time x is set to 0, the second time it is set to (1 << 31) and the third time it is back to 0.

Comment: This is not a message mandated by the C standard; it is a feature of the C compiler, and you did not say which compiler you are using, or with what options. Edit the question and/or its tags to indicate the compiler. It is common that casting an expression to `void` is used to tell the compiler to non-use of the value is deliberately, so `(void) (HSEM->RLR[2] == (HSEM_CM4_CORE_ID | HSEM_PROC_ID | (1 << 31)));` might work.

Comment: That said, what is the semaphore here? `HSEM->RLR[2]`? If so, why would not `HSEM->RLR[2];` suffice to lock the semaphore if, as you write, reading it locks it? What purpose does the comparison building on that serve?

Comment: Further, how do you know evaluating the expression in the question would read the semaphore? If the compiler does not know it is special, then it could optimize the expression to no operation, even if you include the cast to `void` to suppress the warning. Usually, if you need to ensure there is a read, you need to tell the compiler the object is special, such as qualifying it as `void` or giving it some attribute.

Comment: Why is `HSEM->RLR[2] == (HSEM_CM4_CORE_ID | HSEM_PROC_ID | (1 << 31));` the correct code rather than `HSEM->RLR[2] == 0;`?

Comment: [Testing at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/8Ph5or5d6) shows casting to `void` does silence the warning. Edit the question to provide a [mre]. State the GCC version number and the command-line switches and show the full exact text of the error message.

Comment: Which kind of optimization did you choose? Did you try -O0? Is the register defined with eg. volatile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my understanding of the procedure to use the [STM32H745 hardware semaphores](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/training/technical/product_training/group0/2a/6a/df/e1/3b/52/48/b7/STM32H7-System-Hardware_Semaphore_HSEM/files/STM32H7-System-Hardware_Semaphore_HSEM.pdf/_jcr_content/translations/en.STM32H7-System-Hardware_Semaphore_HSEM.pdf), but I could be wrong. The document should provide coding examples instead of schematics.

When you read the semaphore, the value read will depend if the semaphore was free or not, but if it was free, the reading process will lock it and must unlock it when done:

```
while (HSEM->RLR[2] != HSEM_CM4_CORE_ID | 0x0000 | (1U << 31)) {
    /* semaphore was locked by another core/process, wait a bit */
    nanosleep(1000);
}
/* semaphore was locked, we can proceed */
[...]
/* unlock the semaphore */
HSEM->RLR[2] = (HSEM_CM4_CORE_ID | HSEM_PROC_ID);
```

If you are certain the semaphore is free and just mean to lock it, just read the register:

```
/* lock the semaphore */
(void)HSEM->RLR[2];
```

`HSEM` is `#defined` in the STM **stm32h723xx.h** header as a pointer to a memory mapped `HSEM_TypeDef` structure where `RLR` is defined as an `__IO` qualified array of 32 `uint32_t`. `__IO` is defined in **core_cm7.h** as `volatile`. Hence the compiler will generate code to read the value whether the value is used or not and the `(void)` cast means *do not complain about this value not being used*, effectively silencing the compiler warning.

Comment: I need to apologize. I was totally on the wrong track. Sorry about that, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

So for completeness sake referring to my example above in the initial question, the correct code with the suppressed warning looks like this (Thanks to @chqrlie and @Eric Postpischil):

```
#define HSEM_CM4_CORE_ID (1 << 8)  // CPU2 is CM4
#define HSEM_PROC_ID (0 << 0)
volatile uint32_t x;
x = HSEM->R[2] & (1 << 31);                     // Read semaphore 2.
(void) HSEM->RLR[2].                            // Lock semaphore 2.
x = HSEM->R[2] & (1 << 31);                     // Read semaphore 2.
HSEM->R[2] = HSEM_CM4_CORE_ID | HSEM_PROC_ID;   // Release semaphore 22.
x = HSEM->R[2] & (1 << 31);
```